# Interest Rates and compounding periods

Tags: calculation, interest-rate

How can interest be compounded quarterly but with payments made on a monthly basis? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3):

The monthly basis calculation uses a rate converted from the quarterly compounded rate.  For example 10% per annum compounded quarterly, `q`

```
q = 0.10

effective annual rate, r = (1 + q/4)^4 - 1 = 0.103813
```

See [Effective interest rate calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation)

```
monthly rate, m = (1 + r)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.826484 %
```

$100 compounded monthly for 12 months

```
$100 (1 + m)^12 = $110.38
```

Or compounded quarterly for 4 quarters

```
$100 (1 + q/4)^4 = $110.38
```

Finally, same rate expressed as a nominal annual rate compounded monthly

```
12 m = 9.91781 %
```